# Top-aligned subfigure with bottom-aligned caption

Tags: captions, vertical-alignment, subfloats, subcaption

This is a follow-up to an earlier question regarding [left-aligning subfigure captions](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/152692/left-align-captions-with-respect-to-subfigure).

Having achieved the left-alignment goal, I would now like the *caption* of the subfigure to be bottom-aligned, while having the subfigure itself be top-aligned. As an example, in the figure below, subfigures (a) and (b) would share an uppermost edge, and their captions would share a lowermost edge, and similarly for subfigures (c) and (d). This is most appropriate for the overall layout style of my document and also the content of the subfigures themselves.

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[font=footnotesize]{subcaption}
\usepackage[draft]{graphicx}

\begin{document}
\begin{figure}[!ht]
\captionsetup[subfigure]{justification=justified,singlelinecheck=false}
\centering
\begin{subfigure}[b]{0.3\textwidth}
\includegraphics[scale=0.8]{fig/workflow-S}
\caption{workflow $S$}
\end{subfigure}
\begin{subfigure}[b]{0.5\textwidth}
\includegraphics[scale=0.8]{fig/workflow-S-run}
\caption{run of $S$}
\end{subfigure}
\vskip 8pt
\begin{subfigure}[b]{0.3\textwidth}
\includegraphics[scale=0.8]{fig/workflow-S'}
\caption{workflow $S'$}
\end{subfigure}
\begin{subfigure}[b]{0.5\textwidth}
\includegraphics[scale=0.8]{fig/workflow-S'-run}
\caption{run of $S'$}
\end{subfigure}
\caption{Here's a figure}
\end{figure}
\end{document}
```

I've experimented with the `minipage` settings for `subfigure`, specifically using `[t]` instead of `[b]`, but it seems to have no effect. I'm unsure as to whether a position of `[t]` would produce the right effect anyway, or whether it would shift the captions up as well.

Why is `[t]` not working here, and what's the right way to produce the layout I need?

*The solution should generalise to an arbitrary number of subfigures per row, subfigures which are text or tables rather than images, and should not require any hard-coded sizes.*

Comment: (+1) for asking two separate questions.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Here's a flexible solution; in a `figure` environment you define with `\xsubfigure` the objects you need and then arrange them as you like. Each command has as a first argument a symbolic key to be used in `\makerow`; the second argument defines the objects via a key-value syntax (add `\label` in the body of `caption`, if needed).

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[font=footnotesize]{subcaption}
\usepackage[demo]{graphicx}

\usepackage{xparse}
\ExplSyntaxOn
\NewDocumentCommand{\xsubfigure}{ m m }
 {% #1 is a symbolic key, #2 is a list of key-value pairs
  \roly_xsubfigure:nn { #1 } { #2 }
 }
\NewDocumentCommand{\makerow}{ m }
 {% #1 is a list of symbolic keys
  \roly_makerow:n { #1 }
 }

% define the keys
\keys_define:nn { roly/subfigures }
 {
  width .tl_set:N = \l_roly_subfig_width_tl,
  body .tl_set:N = \l_roly_subfig_body_tl,
  caption .tl_set:N = \l_roly_subfig_caption_tl,
 }

% the needed variables
\dim_new:N \l_roly_row_height_dim
\box_new:N \l_roly_body_box

% this is the inner command that stores the properties
\cs_new_protected:Npn \roly_xsubfigure:nn #1 #2
 {
  \prop_if_exist:cTF { l_roly_subfig_#1_prop }
   {
    \prop_clear:c { l_roly_subfig_#1_prop }
   }
   {
    \prop_new:c { l_roly_subfig_#1_prop }
   }
  \keys_set:nn { roly/subfigures } { #2 }
  \prop_put:cnV { l_roly_subfig_#1_prop } { width } \l_roly_subfig_width_tl
  \prop_put:cnV { l_roly_subfig_#1_prop } { body } \l_roly_subfig_body_tl
  \prop_put:cnV { l_roly_subfig_#1_prop } { caption } \l_roly_subfig_caption_tl
 }

% this is the inner command for producing a row
\cs_new_protected:Npn \roly_makerow:n #1
 {
  % get the heights of the objects on a row
  \dim_zero:N \l_roly_row_height_dim
  \clist_map_inline:nn { #1 }
   {
    \hbox_set:Nn \l_roly_body_box
     {
      \prop_item:cn { l_roly_subfig_##1_prop } { body }
     }
    \dim_compare:nT { \box_ht:N \l_roly_body_box > \l_roly_row_height_dim }
     {
      \dim_set:Nn \l_roly_row_height_dim { \box_ht:N \l_roly_body_box }
     }
   }
  % produce a line
  \clist_map_inline:nn { #1 }
   {
    % a subfigure is set here
    \begin{subfigure}[t]{ \prop_item:cn { l_roly_subfig_##1_prop } { width } }
    \raggedright
    \vspace{0pt} % for top alignment
    % the body is set in a suitably dimensioned parbox
    \parbox[t][\l_roly_row_height_dim]{\textwidth}{
      \prop_item:cn { l_roly_subfig_##1_prop } { body }
    }
    % add the caption
    \caption{ \prop_get:cn { l_roly_subfig_##1_prop } { caption } }
    \end{subfigure}
    \hspace{2em} % some space between the objects in a row
   }
   \unskip\\ % end up the row
 }
\ExplSyntaxOff
\begin{document}

\begin{figure}
\captionsetup[subfigure]{justification=justified,singlelinecheck=false}
\centering

\xsubfigure{A}{
  width=0.3\textwidth,
  body={\includegraphics[width=3cm,height=2cm]{fig/workflow-S}},
  caption={workflow $S$ and some text added to go to the next line}
}
\xsubfigure{B}{
  width=0.5\textwidth,
  body={\includegraphics[width=6cm,height=2.5cm]{fig/workflow-S-run}},
  caption={run of $S$}
}
\xsubfigure{C}{
  width=0.3\textwidth,
  body={\includegraphics[width=2cm,height=1.5cm]{fig/workflow-S'}},
  caption={workflow $S'$}
}
\xsubfigure{D}{
  width=0.5\textwidth,
  body={\includegraphics[width=4cm,height=1cm]{fig/workflow-S'-run}},
  caption={run of $S'$}
}

\makerow{A,B}

\medskip

\makerow{C,D}

\caption{Here's a figure}
\end{figure}
\end{document}
```

Note that if you're not satisfied with the arrangement, you can rearrange the subfigures by saying, for instance,

```
\makerow{A,D}

\medskip

\makerow{C,B}
```

In the example I set height and width for every `\includegraphics`, as I don't have your images, but you can use the keys you prefer.

[image]

Comment: This is excellent, thanks. Well worth the 50 bounty!

Comment: This has been a while, but if i copy the above code verbatim, I get the error "Missing number, treated as zero". Is there any explanation to this?

Comment: @user1018513 I tried again (copying from scratch), but I get no error. Are you sure your TeX distribution is up-to-date?

Comment: Very nice solution! I got an error but was able to fix it by replacing `\prop_get:cn` with `\prop_item:cn `

Comment: @Michael Which is what it should be nowadays. Fixed

Answer (score 7):

**Solution Idea**

Put the images inside boxes with a fixed height (use `\vtop` to create
top aligned boxes). Use these boxes as images
to be included in `subfigure`.

The two images which are placed side-by-side are to be given 
identical heights as the first argument of 
`\imagebox`. The second argument is the `\includegraphics` command.

**Solution Code**

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{caption}
\usepackage[font=footnotesize]{subcaption}
\usepackage[draft]{graphicx}

\def\imagebox#1#2{\vtop to #1{\null\hbox{#2}\vfill}}

\begin{document}
\begin{figure}[!ht]
  \captionsetup[subfigure]{justification=justified,singlelinecheck=false}
  \centering
  \begin{subfigure}[b]{0.3\textwidth}
    \imagebox{37.5mm}{\includegraphics[scale=0.8]{fig/workflow-S}}
    \caption{workflow $S$}
  \end{subfigure}
  \begin{subfigure}[b]{0.5\textwidth}
    \imagebox{37.5mm}{\includegraphics[scale=0.8]{fig/workflow-S-run}}
    \caption{run of $S$}
  \end{subfigure}
  \vspace{5.0mm}
  \begin{subfigure}[t]{0.3\textwidth}
    \imagebox{27.5mm}{\includegraphics[scale=0.8]{fig/workflow-S'}}
    \caption{workflow $S'$}
  \end{subfigure}
  \begin{subfigure}[t]{0.5\textwidth}
    \imagebox{27.5mm}{\includegraphics[scale=0.8]{fig/workflow-S'-run}}
    \caption{run of $S'$}
  \end{subfigure}
  \caption{Here's a figure}
\end{figure}
\end{document}
```

**Output**

[image]

**Limitations**

I wish I could come up with a more general solution. Manually setting (needs
trial and error) the
heights for all the *pairs* is a bother. If I could find
a solution where something in the preamble (or a macro definition) could take care of the whole
document that would have been perfect.

If you have only a few figures to be aligned like this, this solution should
work. But if you have hundreds of figures like this, you will want to 
write a more general macro with two arguments where the two arguments will be the two images
to be top aligned. The macro will first measure the height of the two, take the bigger one, then create two `subfigure`s, where `\imagebox` is called inside
using the bigger height previously found.

Comment: Yes, it's not so nice having the guestimate the desired height for reach row. (And I'd want a solution which generalises to n images per row, I guess.)

Still, your approach could be a useful stop-gap. I have maybe dozen figures of this nature, so this is workable, although awkward. Thanks.

Comment: I've experimented with your solution but the manual image sizes is impractical. I've therefore started a bounty on more general solution; I'm not sure if the question is really "widely applicable to a large audience", but I believe there should be a canonical solution.