# Subfloat: How to align subcaption of image to same elevation as other subcaption?

Tags: vertical-alignment, captions, subfloats, subcaption, subfig

Assumed we have two images with different heights. Both images are aligned to the top via `valign=t`.

---

**Minimum working example (MWE):**

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{subfig}
\usepackage[export]{adjustbox}

\begin{document}

\begin{figure}[h]
    \centering
    \subfloat[This is image A]{\includegraphics[width=0.45\textwidth, valign=t]{example-image-16x10}}\qquad
    \subfloat[This is image B]{\includegraphics[width=0.45\textwidth, valign=t]{example-image-10x16}}\\
    \caption{Caption for images A and B}
\end{figure}

\end{document}
```

---

**Screenshot of the result:**

[image: Screenshot of the result]

---

**Description of the issue:**

Unfortunately the corresponding caption also moves up to the top with this command.

While both images should remain at the top, the left image caption should move down to the red dashed elevation line of the other caption for better appearance.

How to do so?

Comment: Related questions using the `subcaption` package: https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/152818/134144  and the `floatrow` package: https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/389970/134144

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Alignment generally involves using baselines, but in this case you need to add a gap between the image and the caption.  You will also need to compute the difference between the heights of the two images.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{subcaption}
\usepackage{graphicx}

\begin{document}

\begin{figure}[htp]
    \centering
    \sbox0{\includegraphics[width=0.45\textwidth]{example-image-16x10}}% measure image
    \sbox1{\includegraphics[width=0.45\textwidth]{example-image-10x16}}% measure image
    \begin{subfigure}{\wd0}
      \usebox0%
      \vspace{\dimexpr \ht1-\ht0}% fill space
      \caption{This is image A}
    \end{subfigure}\qquad% I prefer \hfil
    \begin{subfigure}{\wd1}
      \usebox1
      \caption{This is image B}
    \end{subfigure}
    \caption{Caption for images A and B}
\end{figure}

\end{document}
```

[image: demo]

Answer (score 2):

`floatrow` is [recommended by Overleaf](https://www.overleaf.com/learn/latex/Positioning_images_and_tables#Further_reading) "for advanced caption managing of floating elements (tables and figures)".

It requires changing the environment a bit, but don't be put off by the apparent added complexity because it works very well.

Example:

```latex
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{subcaption}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{floatrow}

\begin{document}

\begin{figure}[h!]
    \centering
    \floatsetup{heightadjust=all, valign=t}
    \ffigbox{
        \begin{subfloatrow}
            \ffigbox[\FBwidth]{
                {\includegraphics[width=0.45\textwidth]{example-image-16x10}}
                {\caption{This is image A}
            }
            \ffigbox[\FBwidth]{
                {\includegraphics[width=0.45\textwidth]{example-image-10x16}}
                {\caption{This is image B}
            }
        \end{subfloatrow}
    }
    {\caption{Caption for images A and B}}
\end{figure}

\end{document}
```

[image: Image of working example]

Some features of this method:

- You can swap `valign=t` for `valign=c` if you want the images vertically centred
- The subcaptions will be centred on the relevant image, thanks to `\FBwidth`. If the subcaptions are longer than the image width, they'll wrap

Answer (score 1):

A solution with minipages and subcaption package:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{subcaption}
\usepackage[export]{adjustbox}
\usepackage{lipsum}

\begin{document}
\lipsum[1]    
\begin{figure}[h]
    \centering
    \begin{minipage}[t]{0.45\textwidth}
    \centering
    \includegraphics[width=\textwidth, valign=t]{example-image-16x10}
    \end{minipage}\hspace{\fill}
    \begin{minipage}[t]{0.45\textwidth}
    \centering
    \includegraphics[width=\textwidth, valign=t]{example-image-10x16}
    \end{minipage}
    \begin{minipage}[t]{0.45\textwidth}
    \captionof{subfigure}{This is image A}
    \end{minipage}\hspace{\fill}
    \begin{minipage}[t]{0.45\textwidth}
    \captionof{subfigure}{This is image B}
    \end{minipage}
    \caption{Caption for images A and B}
\end{figure}

\end{document}
```

[image]

**Edit:** Adding **parentheses** in subcaptions' label **and a vertical space** between images and captions:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{subcaption}
\captionsetup[subfigure]{labelformat = parens}
\usepackage[export]{adjustbox}
\usepackage{lipsum}

\begin{document}
\lipsum[1]    
\begin{figure}[h]
    \centering
    \begin{minipage}[t]{0.45\textwidth}
    \centering
    \includegraphics[width=\textwidth, valign=t]{example-image-16x10}
    \end{minipage}\hspace{\fill}
    \begin{minipage}[t]{0.45\textwidth}
    \centering
    \includegraphics[width=\textwidth, valign=t]{example-image-10x16}
    \end{minipage}
    \vspace{5pt}

    \begin{minipage}[t]{0.45\textwidth}
    \captionof{subfigure}{This is image A}
    \end{minipage}\hspace{\fill}
    \begin{minipage}[t]{0.45\textwidth}
    \captionof{subfigure}{This is image B}
    \end{minipage}
    \caption{Caption for images A and B}
\end{figure}

\end{document}
```

Comment: Thanks a lot for your help! Unfortunately the `subcaption` of the right image is aligned very close to the image now. How to repair this?

Comment: Welcome... See edit. The advantage of minipages in figures and tables (with the help of `subcaption` package) is the full control of the placements and sizes