# Bottom-align caption in subfloats

Tags: floats, captions, adjustbox, subfig

I am trying to align the subcaption of two vertically aligned subfigures of different sizes, this is my code, how can I modify it to obtain the desired result?

```
\documentclass[12pt,twoside]{report}
\usepackage{subfig}
\usepackage[export]{adjustbox}
\begin{document}
        
\begin{figure}[h]
    \subfloat[][\emph{subcaption}\label{fig:fig1}]
            {\includegraphics[width=.45\textwidth, valign=t]{imm/fig1.eps}} \quad
        \subfloat[][\emph{subcaption}\label{fig:fig2}]
            {\includegraphics[width=.45\textwidth, valign=t]{imm/fig2.eps}}
        \caption{Twoo figures}
        \label{fig:figwsub}
\end{figure}
    
\end{document}
```

The problem is that captions are stick to the bottom of figures of different sizes, so they are not aligned.

Here there is the result of my code (with my images).
[image]

I would like to have a more visually pleasant positioning of the captions.

Thanks everybody.

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SE!

Comment: Possible duplicate https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/152818/top-aligned-subfigure-with-bottom-aligned-caption

Comment: Yes, but how do I add lables to subfigures with the accepted solution?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Maybe I did not quite get what you want, but to me, you seem to want to align the two images on the top while still having the subcaptions on the same line. So, why not just place both images in `\parbox`es that have the same height (without even the need to load the `adjustbox` package)?

```
\documentclass[12pt,twoside]{report}
\usepackage{subfig, graphicx}
\begin{document}
        
\begin{figure}[h]
    \subfloat[][\emph{subcaption}\label{fig:fig1}]
            {\parbox[b][5cm][t]{.45\textwidth}{\includegraphics[width=.45\textwidth]{example-image-a}}} 
    \hfill
    \subfloat[][\emph{subcaption}\label{fig:fig2}]
            {\parbox[b][5cm][t]{.45\textwidth}{\includegraphics[width=.45\textwidth, height=30mm]{example-image-b}}}
        \caption{Twoo figures}
        \label{fig:figwsub}
\end{figure}
    
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: This does exactly what I needed, thank you!